# Some kind of appeal process for questions marked duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Once a question is marked as duplicate, how do you go about getting it re-opened after you have edited it to make it clearer the question is more specific/unique?

[the post in question](https://serverfault.com/questions/587549/heartbleed-which-specific-services-must-be-restarted)

Comment: sudo lsof -n | grep ssl | grep DEL

Comment: If this was not fully answered in the target question, it should be.

Comment: That command only works if openssl gets a new version number on a given system though, iain, and since the patch is backported on most distros the version doesn't change

Comment: @xref: That is not my experience on CentOS which is a backport but then again I was in a position to be able to reboot anyway.

Comment: The Answers below are preferred, especially Nathan's. But you can always Flag a Question and explain what's going on too.

Answer (score 7):

When a closed/dupe post is edited, it automatically is dumped into a special queue ("nominated" for reopening) and enough votes will get it reopened.

Answer (score 4):

Meta is your venue to appeal closure (though usually we prefer you wait and let the normal reopening process take place [as Nathan C outlined](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6235/32986).

Having looked at your question it adds some value on top of the marked duplicate, so I've reopened it.